# drupal menu item not active

Tags: drupal, menu

when my primary menu is like item menu1/submenu1.2, de li gets the class active, so i can style it, for example in a different color.

however, if i go to page menu1/submenu1.2/153 then the active class is missing.

Or anything like menu1/submenu1.2/* is the active class missing.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example of `menu1/submenu1.2/153` the active class should have moved to `153`. You can still style `submenu1.2` differently by looking for the `active-trail` class on the `<li>`

For example, if you go to `admin/content/comment` the menu's html should look similar like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="expanded active-trail">
    <a href="/drupalsite/?q=admin">Administer</a>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="expanded first active-trail">
        <a title="Manage your site's content." href="/drupalsite/?q=admin/content">Content management</a>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="leaf first active-trail">
            <a class="active" title="List and edit site comments and the comment moderation queue." href="/drupalsite/?q=admin/content/comment">Comments</a> 
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

That means you can style the `admin` and `content` links by using CSS something like the following:

```
li.active-trail a {
    /*Whatever style here*/
}
```